# Fetch Database Value in multiple textbox while selecting dropdown in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two pages **add_admin.php** and **ajax_admin.php** when i select name in dropdown it display FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME and LASTNAME in TEXTBOXES.

HERE is My Code:

**add_admin.php**

```
<!-- Department -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" >
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="faculty_name" name="faculty_name" class="form-control" onchange='fetch_select(this.value)' required>
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please Select Faculty</option>
        <?php
            $query = mysql_query("select * from faculty_details");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['FACULTY_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['FIRSTNAME']." ".$row['MIDDLENAME']." ".$row['LASTNAME'];?></option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
</div>

<!-- First Name -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i></div>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="First Name" value="">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

other text box are there contaisn middlename, lastname

**Ajax Code**

```
function fetch_select(val)
{
    $.ajax
    ({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'ajax_admin.php',
    data: 
    {
        get_option:val
    },
    success: function (response) 
    {
        $('#fname').val(response);
    }
});
```

**ajax_admin.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
    {
        $state = $_POST['get_option'];
        $find=mysql_query("select * from faculty_details where    FACULTY_ID=$state");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($find))
        {
        echo "$row[FIRSTNAME]";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: please some one help me in this query how i get multiple textbox value in PHP using AJAX

Comment: It's not clear where are you stuck. Assuming your code is working you should change in ajax_admin.php  echo "$row[FIRSTNAME]"; to  echo "$row['FIRSTNAME']"; to get results displayed.

Comment: and then change it to `print_r(htmlspecialchars($row['FIRSTNAME']));`  so you dont get hacked

Comment: FIRSTNAME is fetching in FIRST TEXTBOX I WANT TO FETCH MIDDLENAME tooo in other textbox

Comment: So you want to create a multi-value select box?

Comment: I have one select box on select one record the value are fetch from database and print FirstName, MiddleName in textboxes but i dont know how to do it...

Comment: For EG.. I have FullName : Ayan Arif Shaikh when i select this is drop down it display in textboxes TEXTBOX1: Ayan TEXTBOX2: Arif TEXTBOX3: Shaikh

Comment: @AyanShaikh Please check the ans.

Comment: @SarathKumar thank you brother its working for me

Comment: @AyanShaikh  accept the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the result as json from the server so that you can easily use it in jQuery:
**ajax-admin.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
{
   $state = $_POST['get_option'];
   $row1=array();
   $find=mysql_query("select firstname,middlename,lastname from faculty_details where  FACULTY_ID=$state");

   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($find))
  {
    $row1[]=$row;
  }
  die(json_encode($row1));
}
```

**Ajax Code**

```
function fetch_val(val) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax-admin.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{"get_option":val},
        dataType:"JSON",
        success:function(data){
            $('#fname').val((data[0].firstname));
            $('#mname').val((data[0].middlename));
            $('#lname').val((data[0].lastname));

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: sir please explain more about this code while adding comment to each line whereever necessary to me & future readers also, which gives help us.

Comment: @KUMAR can tell me about what?

Comment: why we use `$_POST[]` here `$state = $_POST['get_option'];` not `$_GET[];`

Comment: and why you use `die` before `die(json_encode($row1));` not `echo`?

Comment: @KUMAR Here we using $_POST because request type is POST that we set it in ajax request.
we put die insted echo, because we may put above php code in the any php file if we put echo it will execute the below lines that's unnecessary. So we stoping the code executing below line by adding die

Comment: means we can put `ajax-admin.php` php code in this `add_admin.php` php file also.

Comment: @KUMAR you can put